# Joomla Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1048576 bytes)

Tags: php, memory, joomla

I'm currently running Joomla 1.5.8 on a live server. I can only make certain changes to the website such as text content updates in articles. However any modification to a module returns this titles error with error reporting on.

Without it returns a generic Server Error 500.

I've tried changing the permissions of alot of different folders and have tried to manipulate the htaccess file as well but I still have had no luck. I did not setup the site originally and have been brought into this project with functioning features already existing, I just cannot make any changes to them or new ones.

Full error is: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1048576 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php on line 147

Comment: You need to up your configuration `memory_limit` if Joomla simply uses this much memory. You could also check `file.php` at line 147 and figure out what huge file it is that the script is loading.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770179/1607098)

Comment: Try disabling non core plugins one at a time until you find the one that is breaking things.

Comment: I've tried to up the memory_limit in htaccess but doesn't seem to change it:

Comment: file.php line 142 to 149 is: // Connect the FTP client
   jimport('joomla.client.ftp');
   $ftp = & JFTP::getInstance($FTPOptions['host'], $FTPOptions['port'], null, $FTPOptions['user'], $FTPOptions['pass']);
  }

  foreach ($files as $file)
  {
   $file = JPath::clean($file);

Comment: How about updating to the latest 1.5 version at least?!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```